# Need help I made this recipe and I doubled the recipe and it looked dry

Tags: cookies

I need help to fit these batches I already rolled them up can I go ahead fix it. what can I do to fix these batches so it doesn't crumble and look dry. i have I included the recipe I used. Like I said I doubled it . thank you

3/4 cup granulated sugar
3/4 cup packed brown sugar
1 cup butter, softened
1 teaspoon vanilla
1 egg
2 1/4 cups all-purpose flour
1 teaspoon baking soda
1/2 teaspoon salt
1 package (12 ounces) semisweet chocolate chips (2 cups)
1 c

Comment: I'm not certain what the question is ? you want to double the recipe and it became too dry ? before or after baking it?

Comment: Did you refrigerate the dough? It may be too cold.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting from the same ingredient list as [Nestle Toll House Cookies](https://www.verybestbaking.com/recipes/18476/) but are rolling it out? Please add more information to your recipe: how are you preparing and mixing the ingredients? Do you let the mixture sit for a time at one or multiple stages? How are you doing the rolling? How big are the portions? The baking? What is the final product? How long did they sit and under what conditions before you tested them and found them too dry and crumbly?

It's hard to give good advice without more detail, but if you're ending up with dryer, crumbly product, things you might try:

1. Increase your brown-to-white sugar ratio (keep the total amount of sugar the same),
2. Instead of two eggs, use one egg and one (or two!) egg yolks,
3. [Make sure your baking soda is still OK](https://www.thespruceeats.com/how-to-tell-if-baking-soda-is-still-good-1388327).

If you're shooting for something cookie-like, [Dan might have some advice for you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCt3xhKCX1k).